# typescript definition from lib.d.ts

Tags: typescript

Please see the code [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20IQuery%20=%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20idxName%3a%20%27session%27,%0D%0A%20%20%20%20//keyRange%3a%20window.IDBKeyRange.only%28%271%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20keyRange%3a%20IDBKeyRange.only%28%271%27%29%0D%0A%7D;)

```
var IQuery = {
    idxName: 'session',
    //keyRange: window.IDBKeyRange.only('1')
    keyRange: IDBKeyRange.only('1')
};
```

why it doesn't recognize `IDBKeyRange` ?

in `lib.d.ts`, I see these definitions.

```
interface IDBKeyRange {
    upper: any;
    upperOpen: boolean;
    lower: any;
    lowerOpen: boolean;
    bound(lower: any, upper: any, lowerOpen?: boolean, upperOpen?: boolean): IDBKeyRange;
    only(value: any): IDBKeyRange;
    lowerBound(bound: any, open?: boolean): IDBKeyRange;
    upperBound(bound: any, open?: boolean): IDBKeyRange;
}
declare var IDBKeyRange: {
    prototype: IDBKeyRange;
    new (): IDBKeyRange;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2048) in the lib.d.ts file. You can [get an updated copy from the CodePlex site](https://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/50bc3ffe99ab89828cbde12d9e39c809156bdf6c).